# Derivative of distributions inner product

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The dot product of two distributions $u(s)$ and $v(s)$, for $s$ the parametric coordinates, is written as $u(s)^{\intercal} \, v(s)$. What would a closed form for the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left( u(s)^{\intercal} \, v(s)\right)$ be? My confusion constitutes on the following, for i from 1 to the dimension of $s$:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial s_i} \left( u(s)^{\intercal} \, v(s)\right) = \sum\limits_i \left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial s_i} u_i\right) \, v_i + u_i \, \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial s_i} v_i\right) \right]$

Example: $\frac{\partial}{\partial [x \, y]^{\intercal}} \begin{bmatrix} x & y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2x \\ 2y \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Could you give us some context? For instance, what are your thoughts on the problem? Where are you getting stuck? Do you have an idea as to what the answer is supposed to be? Also, are we meant to interpret $\frac{\partial }{\partial s}$ as a [distributional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Differential_operators)? If so, then is this your primary source of confusion?

Comment: I added several lines to improve the question comprehension. I thank you for improving my skills.

Comment: Thanks for explaining things a bit further, but unfortunately I'm still confused. The question made it seem as though $s$ is supposed to be a scalar parameter. If it's not, then what do you mean by "for $s$ the parametric coordinates"? Assuming that $s$ is meant to be a vector of several components, it seems like your primary confusion is understanding what exactly $\frac{\partial }{\partial s}(u^\top v)$ means, as opposed to $\frac{\partial }{\partial s_i} (u^\top v)$. Am I correct?

Comment: The coordinate parameters are the variables which describes the distribution. The $s_i$ derivative constitutes on the step which bring ease to the derivation.

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is it that you do not understand?

Comment: What does the matrix looks like if one concatenate the rows obtained by element-wise derivation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$ of $f(s) = u(s)^\top v(s)$ can be presented either as a row vector or a column vector. If it is presented as a row vector, then we have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = \pmatrix{\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial s_1}\right]^Tv + u^T\left[\frac{\partial v}{\partial s_1}\right] & 
 \cdots &
\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial s_d}\right]^Tv + u^T\left[\frac{\partial v}{\partial s_d}\right]}.
$$
We note that
$$
\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial s_k}\right]^Tv + v^T\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial s_k}\right] = \sum_{i=1}^d \left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial s_k}v_i + u_i\frac{\partial vI}{\partial s_k} \right).
$$

This can also be written as
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = \left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right]^Tv + u^T\left[\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\right],
$$
where $\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}$ denotes the matrix
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s} = \pmatrix{\frac{\partial u}{\partial s_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial u}{\partial s_d}}.
$$

Comment: I do not comprehend. Why doesn't the matrix form present s derivatives respective  to v?

Comment: @Bruno I don't understand why you believe it should. Can you give me any other example of a derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ where we use derivatives of $x$ with respect to $f$?

Comment: There is an example on the statement.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto In your example, you have a derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, not a derivative of $x$ with respect to $f$.

Comment: I wrote the statement wrong, I apologize. I expected a derivative of v respective to s.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto see my latest edit

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto Your question would have been much easier to answer if you had said "I do not understand what the matrix $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$ should look like."

Comment: I understand. Are general statements more comprehensible?

Comment: @Bruno **Simpler** statements are more comprehensible. Your question was written in the form "I have confusion with [equation]." This does not answer the question of what exactly it is that you want explained, or why the equation is confusing.

Comment: It was clear to me when I wrote the question.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto Of course **you** understand what you are thinking about, but the point of communication is to make other people understand what you are thinking about.

Comment: Of course. Communication is hard. I wonder how humans are able to perform it.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto It is absolutely a skill, and it takes practice. In any case, I'm happy we were able to come to a satisfactory conclusion

Comment: Wait a second! The dimensions do not match: block times column = row. Row times block = row.